# Many to Many Hibernate mapping with extra column

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, model-associations

I've seen this question on here a few times, however none of the answers fix my issue.

I'm trying to deconstruct a many-to-many relationship down to seperate many-to-one and one-to-many entities so I can add additional columns. From what I have, the main entity saves to the database, but the intermediate does not. If anyone can figure out what's going on I would very much appreciate it. I tried doing this the other way with the primary key composite (aka: @AssociationOverride) but it also did not work. I've scowered the web but cannot find an answer to my issue here.

This is my main entity, MaintOrder:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="maint_orders")
public class MaintOrder extends PersistedObject implements java.io.Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="maintOrder")
private Set<ManPowerLine> manPower = new HashSet<ManPowerLine>() ;

public void addManPower(ManPower manPower, Integer quantity, Float price) {
  ManPowerLine mpLine = new ManPowerLine();
  mpLine.setManPower(manPower);
  mpLine.setMaintOrder(this);
  mpLine.setManPowerID(manPower.getManPowerID());
  mpLine.setMaintOrderID(this.getMaintOrderID());
  mpLine.setQuantity(quantity);
  mpLine.setPrice(price);
  this.manPower.add(mpLine);
    // Also add the association object to the employee.
  manPower.getMaintOrder().add(mpLine);
  }
... getters and setters
}
```

Here is my secondary entity, ManPower:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="man_power")
public class ManPower extends PersistedObject implements java.io.Serializable {

...id's, etc

@OneToMany(mappedBy="manPower", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<ManPowerLine> maintOrder = new HashSet<ManPowerLine>();


public Set<ManPowerLine> getMaintOrder(){
    return maintOrder;
}
public void setMaintOrder(Set<ManPowerLine> maintOrder){
    this.maintOrder  = maintOrder;
}
... other getters and setters
}
```

Here is my intermediate entity, ManPowerLine:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "man_power_line")
@IdClass(ManPowerLineID.class)
public class ManPowerLine extends PersistedObject implements java.io.Serializable {

  @Id
  private Long maintOrderID;
  @Id
  private Long manPowerID;

  @Column(name="quantity")
  private Integer quantity;
  @Column(name="price")
  private Float price;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "maintOrderID", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "maint_order_id")
  private MaintOrder maintOrder;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "manPowerID", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "man_power_id")
  private ManPower manPower;
 ... other getters and setters
 }
```

And my ID entity, ManPowerLineID:

```
public class ManPowerLineID implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long maintOrderID;
private Long manPowerID;

public Long getMaintOrderID(){
    return maintOrderID;
}
public Long getManPowerID(){
    return manPowerID;
}
public void setMaintOrderID(Long maintOrderID){
    this.maintOrderID = maintOrderID;
}
public void setManPowerID(Long manPowerID){
    this.manPowerID = manPowerID;
}


@Override
public int hashCode(){
    return (int)(maintOrderID + manPowerID);
}

@Override   
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if( obj instanceof ManPowerLine){
        ManPowerLineID otherID = (ManPowerLineID)obj;
        boolean hey = (otherID.maintOrderID == this.maintOrderID) && (otherID.manPowerID ==  this.manPowerID);
        return hey;
    }
        return false;

}

}
```

Finally the code which utilizes this is as follows:

```
private void insertObject(  ) {

ServiceLocator locator = new ServiceLocator();
SessionFactory sf = locator.getHibernateSessionFactory();
Session sess = sf.openSession();
Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();

MaintOrder m = new MaintOrder();

... various setters to m

Set manPowerSet = new HashSet();
for(int i = 0; i < manPowerSet.size(); i++){
ManPower mp = new ManPower();
mp = (ManPower) manPowerSet.iterator().next();
m.addManPower(mp, quantity, cost);
}
sess.saveOrUpdate(m);
tx.commit();
sess.close();

}
```

Is it possible that I need to use more then just m.addManPower to add to the line? I've tried adding m.setManPowerLine, but it does not change the result.

Anyways I know its a lot of code to look at, but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I fixed my own issue on this one. The problem was that I didn't set cascade = CascadeType.ALL, in *ALL* the right places. Specifically Here:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="manPower", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ManPowerLine> maintOrder = new ArrayList<ManPowerLine>();
```

Should be:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="manPower", cascade = CascadeType.All)
private List<ManPowerLine> maintOrder = new ArrayList<ManPowerLine>();
```